# How to get the period of oeis.org/A130166 other than by trail?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, recursion, oeis

[oeis.org/A130166](http://oeis.org/A130166) `a(0)=1; a(n)=prime(mod(a(n-1),1000))` starts with:

`1, 2, 3, 5, 11, 31, 127, 709, 5381, 2621, 4591, 4327, 2179, 1063, 307, 2027, 103, 563, 4091, 467, 3319, 2113, 617, 4549, 3967, 7607, 4463, 3299, 1979, 7717, 5431, 3001, 2,...`

The comments say: *Starting with the second term, cycles every 31 terms.*

> Is it possible to get the period of `a(n)` other than by trial?

Comment: I like "trail" (from the title) better than "trial" (from the body).

Comment: Trivially, since $a_n$ only depends on $a_{n-1}$ then the moment you hit a value already seen the sequence will cycle; almost as trivially, there can be only 1000 distinct values in the sequence so the period is limited by that.  Less trivial, the Birthday Paradox suggests that the length of the sequence 'should be' $\approx\sqrt{1000}\approx 31$, possibly modulo a small constant factor.  But other than that, there's so little structure here that I can't see any reason to expect a better method than trial-and-error.

Comment: @RossMillikan oh, anyway. can you put me on the right trail away from trial?

Comment: (And, crotchetily, I'm at a loss to understand why this sequence is in any sense 'good enough' for OEIS; it features a random 'base ten' clamp (the mod by $1000$) that has nothing particular to do with actual decimal representations of the numbers in question, and couples that to a function that's arguably completely unrelated.  If anyone can point me to mathematical content in this sequence I'd love to see it, but at first glance this is less informative than, say, the street numbers of NYC subway stations.)

Comment: Good points, @Steven, thanks. Let's see if anybody is able to use the little structure provided to get something better than trial-and-error...

Comment: @NovaDenizen:  OP chose not to fix this after my comment, so I think it should be left alone.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I'd love to hear more on your feelings about what _is_ good enough; not sure of a good place for it, though.

Comment: @Charles A bit belatedly maybe, but roughly: it seems like a reasonable criteria is that either (a) there are interesting mathematical questions to be _asked_ about the sequence, (b) there are interesting mathematical questions that can be _answered_ by the sequence, or (c) the sequence has either historical or sociological significance.  Obviously eeryone will have their own definition of 'interesting', but I'm not sure what interesting questions can be asked about or answered by this sequence itself.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Thank you. Mind if I quote that?

Comment: Not at all!  May I ask where you're thinking of quoting it to?